# Eclipse Link MongoDB datasource Configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, eclipselink

How to configure JDBC MongoDB datasource with Eclipse Link in Spring Boot application without below mongodb starter dependency **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb**

Added below dependencies in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <org.eclipse.persistence.version>2.7.11</org.eclipse.persistence.version>
</properties>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>          
        <version>3.12.11</version>          
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>4.0.0</version> -->
        <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.version}</version>
        <!-- <version>2.7.11</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
        <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
        <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```